# Reading integer field from Java object with C++ (JNI)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to access "int" field in the Java class from C++; Actually I also tried other types. I can call methods OK though. But not access fields. I get random garbage values instead of what I am expecting.

Here is my Java code:

```
private class MYView extends View {
    public MYView(Context context) { super(context);  five = 555; }
    public int five;
....
}
```

C++ part:

```
jobject view = (jobject) Env->CallObjectMethod(Obj, jfindViewById, 3);
ClassMYView = Env->GetObjectClass(view);
jfieldID f = Env->GetFieldID(ClassMYView, "five", "I");
int i = Env->GetIntField(ClassMYView, f); <-- error is here, class is not object!
```

This is what I get after the C++ code executes

```
view = 0x40521b80 
ClassMYView = 0x40521a70 
f = 0x444727e4
i = 4390958 // supposed to be 555!
```

Please anybody with experience, what am I doing wrong??
Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you want to write

```
jobject obj = (jobject) Env->CallObjectMethod(Obj, jfindViewById, 3);
ClassMYView = Env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID f = Env->GetFieldID(ClassMYView, "five", "I");
int i = Env->GetIntField(obj, f);
```

The compiler doesn't give you an error because basically jobject and jclass are the same type.

Comment: Type signatures for `GetFieldID` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)  - section TYPE SIGNATURES